# If i try to upload audio file in phpmyadmin,its showing an error of #2006 and what is the data type should mention

Tags: mysql, database, audio, phpmyadmin, xampp

If I try to  upload audio file in phpmyadmin,its showing an error of #2006 and what is the data type should mention
SQL query:  Edit

```
INSERT INTO `b7_11386777_test`.`wish` (`pinNo`, `audio`) VALUES 
('1', SOUNDEX(0x52494646b89d430057415645666d74201000000001000100401f0000803e00000200100064617461949d43000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000[...]
```

MySQL said:

> 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

I am going to insert an audio file into mysql database.what are parameters required to get into it and also which data type is to be used to insert audio file into mysql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SOUNDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) is for matching strings (text) that have similar phonetics.  If `audio` is of type [`BLOB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html), you just need to remove `SOUNDEX()` from around the value:

```
INSERT INTO b7_11386777_test.wish (pinNo, audio) VALUES ('1', 0x52494646b8...);
```

However, you really *ought* to store files in your filesystem and record the file's path in your database.